# Functional or non-functional requirement?

Tags: requirements

I'm wondering about functional or non-functional requirements. I have found lot of different definitions for those terms and I can't assign some of my requirement to proper category.

I'm wondering about requirements that aren't connected with some action or have some additional conditions, for example:

1. On the list of selected devices, device can be repeated.
2. Database must contain at least 100 items
3. Currency of some value must be in USD dollar.
4. Device must have a name and power consumption value in Watts.

are those requirements functional or non-functional ?

Comment: Such kind of *discussions* would be more appropriate on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Functional requirements are things the system does.
- Non-functional requirements are quality attributes or aspects of how the system is designed, built or implemented.

Have a look at:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/71621/what-is-the-difference-between-a-non-functional-requirement-and-a-quality-attrib

Comment: Can you assign my 4 example requirements as an example ? I still don't get it 100% sure.